# Pybind11 - gilstate->autoInterpreterState error

Tags: c++, windows, pybind11

Versions:

- **Python**: 3.11
- **Pybind11**: 2.10.1
- **Cmake**: 3.23.0-rc2
- **Compiler:** MSVCC from VS2019

I get a runtime error while trying to import a very simple pybind module (via "import pybindtest"). The error is as follows:

[image]

The cmake:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.12)

# Create the project, called pybindtestproject
# Sets that C++ is needed to build the project
PROJECT(pybindtestproject LANGUAGES CXX)

# The name of the python project that users of Python will import is "pybindtest"
SET(PY_PROJECT pybindtest)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYBIND11_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY})

# Set what source files are needed
SET(PYTHON_PROJECT_SOURCES
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/pybindtestfile.cpp
    )

# Give Cmake a "hint" as to where python is located. If it is not found there, it will fall back to searching
IF(WIN32)
  SET(Python3_ROOT_DIR "C:/Users/tyler.shellberg/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311")
ENDIF()

# Find an installation of Python
FIND_PACKAGE(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development REQUIRED)

# Find an external installation of pybind11
FIND_PACKAGE(pybind11 REQUIRED HINTS "${Python3_SITELIB}")

# This is a wrapper around cmake's add_library
# Creates a module that can be imported by python
# Name must be the same as set by PYBIND11_MODULE in the source file
PYBIND11_ADD_MODULE(${PY_PROJECT} MODULE ${PYTHON_PROJECT_SOURCES})
```

The code:

```
#include <Python.h> 

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

// Creates a function that will be called when an import statement is issued from within Python
PYBIND11_MODULE(pybindtest, m)
{
    m.doc() = "Test python module.";
}
```

I have also tried pulling the latest master of Pybind via Cmake's FetchContent (commit `1f04cc7062e33481c62c78231e9561b318bca67b`), but that did not remove the error.

Comment: I see no "import pybindtest" in your question. Please see http://www.sscce.org/ - post something we can cut'n'paste and reproduce.

Comment: I put it at the top of the question. The command to reproduce would be to open python interactive, then attempt to import the module. How should I phrase that in the question?

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused because I had forgotten to set the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to Debug. Essentially, the Release libraries of python were being used in a Debug build, which caused this opaque error.

I've seen similar things happen with VTK.

Comment: Im working on the same problem now, any chance u can post ur example working repo that works with debug?